# Finding the largest time in an array

Tags: powershell

I have this code and it keeps telling me it cannot compare my variables because they aren't the same type and cannot implement IComparable.

```
$times = Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties PasswordLastSet | Select-Object PasswordLastSet
$maximum = [DateTime]0
foreach($item in $times){
    if($item -gt $maximum){
        $maximum = $item
    }
}
Write-Host $maximum
```

It seems like a pretty straightforward script, but I'm scratching my head on this one.

Comment: maybe replace this `... | Select-Object PasswordLastSet` with this `... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PasswordLastSet`

Comment: $item is of type PSCustomObject. You need to access the property: $item.PasswordLastSet

Comment: [datetime] instances have a CompareTo method, so the code in OP could be changed to `$item.compareto($maximum) -gt 0` (instead of `$item -gt $maximum`). This achieves O(n) running time, which only matters if you have lots of computers to consider (probably more than 1000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [sort](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx) a list of objects by one of their properties and then [select](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) the first (or last) element from the sorted list:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties PasswordLastSet |
  Sort-Object PasswordLastSet -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1
```

If you need just the `DateTime` value you could also expand the property, either before sorting:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties PasswordLastSet |
  Select-Object -Expand PasswordLastSet |
  Sort-Object -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1
```

or afterwards:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties PasswordLastSet |
  Sort-Object PasswordLastSet -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1 -Expand PasswordLastSet
```

Comment: If they just need the `DateTime` value, 'd argue they should forego the O(n log n) version and use the O(n) one: `Measure-Object PasswordLastSet -Maximum`.